# Grails: Why is the JSON from a GET request not getting bound to the command object in the controller action?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Note: I'm using Grails 2.5.5.

This is my method in the controller (I know save() shouldn't be a GET, but I'm just testing things out):

```
def save(Test cmd) {
    println cmd.duration
    println params.duration
}
```

This is my client code:

```
let data = JSON.parse($('#req').val());
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    method: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

When this flow is executed, on the controller side, `cmd.duration` does not print what was sent from the client side (instead it's the default value of zero since duration is typed as an int). On the other hand, `params.duration` does print what was sent from the client side.
 So this indicates that it's not a problem with how the data is getting sent, but instead has to do with some data binding issue?

Also, just for reference, POST works perfectly fine with the above server-side code. The command object gets populated appropriately as long as I change the client code accordingly (changing method type and stringifying the JSON):

```
let data = JSON.parse($('#req').val());
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

I know there are similar questions out there, but it seems like most of them deal with issues with POST requests. So this is a bit different.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just needed to remove the `contentType` in the ajax call on the client side for the GET request. Once I did that, everything worked as expected.

Not sure if that is expected behavior, but it works for me for now.